# Jboss 6.4 : Error while running two instances of the same war on Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x

I'm trying to get two instances of a nearly identical war running on the same jboss instance.  I have changed the context-root in jboss-web.xml in each  war1 and war2 to be different.  However, when i start up jboss, one will start successfully, but the other will fail with the below exception.   Any idea on how to resolve?

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to bind [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension@                                                                                                                       75507f81] at location [service jboss.naming.context.java.com.sun.jersey.config.CDIExtension] [Root exception is org.jb                                                                                                                       oss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.com.sun.jersey.config.CDIExtension is alr                                                                                                                       eady registered]
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.initialize(CDIExtension.java:201)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.beforeBeanDiscovery(CDIExtension.java:302)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
        at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:164)
        at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:15                                                                                                                       4)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java                                                                                                                       :46)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:46)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:335)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:62)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to bind [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension@75507f81] at loca                                                                                                                       tion [service jboss.naming.context.java.com.sun.jersey.config.CDIExtension] [Root exception is org.jboss.msc.service.D                                                                                                                       uplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.com.sun.jersey.config.CDIExtension is already registered]
        at org.jboss.as.naming.util.NamingUtils.namingException(NamingUtils.java:151)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.bind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:93)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.rebind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:109)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.rebind(NamingContext.java:269)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.rebind(NamingContext.java:277)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.initialize(CDIExtension.java:198)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.com.sun.jersey.config.CD                                                                                                                       IExtension is already registered
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:158)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:236)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:742)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:243)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2433)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:345)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.bind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:76)
        ... 29 more

        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java                                                                                                                       :48)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:46)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:335)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:62)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-                                                                                                                       msc.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc.jar:1                                                                                                                       .1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: It seems that Jersey CDI extension tries to bind itself twice in JNDI, Maybe you should try to start EAP with the following system property: "-Dcom.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true"

Comment: @ehsavoie Thank you sir.  your suggestion solved the issue!